# How to find custom view by the custom field

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller where I am adding multiple custom views. What I am trying to do is to access the view that I have added dynamically and to access it on certain triggers such as location updates.

Something like the following... I've simplified the code a bit. But this should give you a fairly good view on what I am trying to achieve.

```
  class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
     //my custom views
     var mapPins = Set<UserPin>()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         createScreen()
         updateScreen() //this happens on location update
         super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func createScreen() {

        let userPinA = UserPin(userID: "ab12319ssdf91dfa2js92kajsdf23kd93", name: "J smith", posX: Int(1500), posY: Int(1800), pictureURL: "sad_face.jpg", direction: 1, colour: "Red", currentTrack: 33, lastTimeConnected: Date())
        mapPins.insert(userPinB)

        //this is actually done dynamically but good enough for the example
        mapPins.insert(userPinB)
        mapPins.insert(userPinC)
        mapPins.insert(userPinD)

        containerView = UIView()

        // adding is not a problem. So far so good!
        for userpin in mapPins
        {
            imageView.addSubview(userpin)
        }

        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    //triggered on location update, just believe it fires for the purpose of this
    func updateScreen()
    {
        //Here is the issue!
        //I want to get to the right view by userID, the same that is updated on my mapPins set, and update the posX and posY (animation is the intention). How do I do that?
        //something like self.view.subviews.view.userID, obviously that does not work. I just don't think I understand enough how custom views work to access the properties of them.

    }
```

This is how my custom view looks. As you can see its a simple view. The userID field is the one that I am actually interested.

```
 import UIKit

    class UserPin: UIView {


        var userID : String?
        var name : String?
        var posX : Int?
        var posY : Int?
        var pictureURL : String?
        var direction : Int?
        var colour : String?
        var currentTrack : Int?
        var lastTimeConnected : Date?

        init(userID: String, name: String, posX: Int, posY: Int, pictureURL: String, direction: Int, colour: String, currentTrack : Int, lastTimeConnected : Date)
        {
            self.userID = userID
            self.name = name
            self.posX = posX
            self.posY = posY
            self.pictureURL = pictureURL
            self.direction = direction
            self.colour = colour
            self.currentTrack = currentTrack
            self.lastTimeConnected = lastTimeConnected

            super.init(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 100, height: 100))
            self.addControls(userID, name: name, posX: posX, posY: posY,  pictureURL: pictureURL, direction: direction,  colour: colour,  currentTrack: currentTrack, lastTimeConnected: lastTimeConnected)
        }
     func addControls(_ userID: String, name: String, posX: Int, posY: Int, pictureURL: String, direction: Int, colour: String, currentTrack : Int, lastTimeConnected : Date) {
    //does stuff on the view with labels and shapes and stuff
    }
```

Comment: You have two (okay) options: 1) Keep an array of your custom views as a property of your VC, 2) Implement KVO in your subviews, which I wouldn't recommend, as it's gotten rather difficult in Swift.

Comment: Ok, but isn't that what my mapPins set is? So how do I access it?

Comment: Two things I'll add to the answer by @dylanthelion. (1) Consider where you can use the tag property/identifier, it may be of help. (2) I'm extremely wary of anything called *updateScreen()* executing in *viewDidLoad()*. It sounds - at least to me - like you expect this to be executed more frequently than it will be. (*viewWillAppear()*, *viewDidAppear()*, and *viewWillLayoutSubviews()* may be more appropriate.)

Comment: @user2091936: with a for...in loop. If you need to access them in a specific order, use an Array. If you need to filter them (like, get the pin with the highest posX value), use filter(:) or reduce(:).

Comment: Ok, I think the easiest way is to create a mapping between the userIDs and the tags. The loop etc is not a difficult thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Dictionary` in your view controller with keys are `userID`s and objects are your `customView`s

This is more efficient if there are many custom views as a `Array` will have to be iterated a lot.